# How can I use Joint Distribution Function to Find the Probability for 2 random variables in a certain interval?

Tags: probability-distributions

We are given this density function :

$$ f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{xy}{96},  & 0<x<4,& 1<y<5 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

and are supposed to find $P(X\ge3, Y\le2)$

rather than using the double integral how can we calculate this probability with the distribution function?

I calculated the joint dist func : $$F(x,y)=\frac{x^2(y^2-1)}{384}$$

then i tried : $P(X\ge3, Y\le2) = F(4, 2)-F(3,1)$

but this gives $\frac{48}{384}$ and the correct answer is $\frac{21}{384}$

Comment: By definition: $F(x,y)=P(X \leq x, Y \leq y)$, so it should be $F(4,2)-F(3,\color{red}{2})$.

Comment: @AnuragA yes thats correct but how did you find that?

Comment: @AnuragA for Y<=2 shouldn't we include the complete interval just like we did with X?

Comment: First draw the rectangular region $[0,4] \times [1,5]$. Then $F(4,2)$ represents the probability over the region $[0,4] \times [1,2]$ and $F(3,2)$ will represent the probability over $[0,3] \times [1,2]$. Now you subtract one from the other.

Comment: @AnuragA Oh now i see it, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the green area of probability in this

The green and purple areas  of probability together represent $F(4,2)$

while the purple area  of probability is $F(3,2)$ not $F(3,1)$

so take the difference

[image]

Comment: thanks now i understand :)